# Set default values for billing information

Tags: 8, commerce

With Drupal 8 and Drupal Commerce 2, I need to set the default values for checkout/billing information. I need to get values from connected user fields.

How could I achieve this?
In Drupal 7 I did this implementing `hook_form_alter()` and modifying the form, but in Drupal 8 the billing information is contained an entity (Profile) and I can't find where to put the default values.

I feel like in `hook_form_alter()` I could create a new Profile entity, set fields from user fields and then set this Profile entity as default value for the billing information form. Is this correct?

There is [a post](https://www.drupal.org/node/2844920) about modifying the profile form (billing or shipping) in order to reload an old profile, set one as default or modifying an existing profile

Unfortunately in my use case its useless. I allow only one billing profile, and I need to provide default values from user fields.